# Multiple requests in one session (TidHTTP)

Tags: delphi, indy

i have a little device which i connect to over http. I send some xml and then wait for the answer.

```
http:tidhttp;
XMLData:TStringStream;

http.Post(DeviceUrl,XMLData);
```

Post method sends the data and waits for the reply(also xml). When that happens session is over, right? But i need to send more data within that session.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: HTTP is a stateless protocol. For sessions, Cookies or a sessionId in the URL are used, so maybe you only need to add a IdCookieHandler

Comment: Define "session"...what enables/tracks it?  Are there steps before this .Post which are assumed?

Comment: @mjn is the linkage of cookie manager and usage of cookies seemless or do we have to do something to make TIdHTTP to use individual cookies?

Comment: @UmairAhmed the cookie manager only has to be assigned to the TIdHTTP component, and then works without any further configuration

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sessions are kept track of on the server end.  `TIdHTTP` is a client component.  HTTP is a stateless protocol, and does not require persistent connections between requests within a single session.  Most servers persist session information from one request to another using either cookies or URL query strings, both of which work with `TIdHTTP`.